# DART - expectAsync does not work with httpRequest

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I am trying to test if asynchronous call happens after httpRequest returns.

Here is my code:

```dart
...       
   var httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
   httpRequest.withCredentials = true;
   httpRequest.open('POST', repositoryURL);
   httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Authorization", auth);
   test('Asynch testing of getting Repositories', (){
     var callback =  expectAsync(() {repositoryListComplete(httpRequest);});
     httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) => callback);     
     httpRequest.onError.listen((ee) => handleError(ee));
     httpRequest.send('');
   });
}

void repositoryListComplete(HttpRequest request){
    print('Testing URL connection for ${repositoryURL}');
...
```

The test stops and the callback seems to be never called.

If I simply use repositoryListComplete as a callback for onLoadEnd, it gets called with no problems.

I found a similar bug report here:

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=16677

I just wonder if I am having the same issue or my code it incorrect?

Edit: -- I changed the code to

```dart
   httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) => callback());
```

and now I am getting this:

```dart
FAIL
1   PASS    Expectation: Checking if all UI components are present.
2   FAIL    Expectation: Asynch testing of getting Repositories. Caught Bad state: Not allowed when tests are running.
package:unittest/unittest.dart 268:21               test
documentviewertest.dart 275:9                       repositoryListComplete
documentviewertest.dart 261:60                      sendRepositoryListRequest.<fn>.<fn>
package:unittest/src/spread_args_helper.dart 94:23  invoke0
documentviewertest.dart 262:51                      sendRepositoryListRequest.<fn>.<fn>
dart:async                                          _BaseZone.bindUnaryCallback.<fn>
Total 1 passed, 1 failed 0 errors
```

I am calling another tests in the repositoryListComplete, but should it matter?

Is expectAsync considered running until the wrapped method returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `callback`

```dart
httpRequest.onLoadEnd.listen((ee) => callback());  // callback() instead of callback
```

`callback` just returns the closure reference.

Comment: Thank you, this advanced me a step ahead, but I still have problem with this test - please, see modified original post.

Comment: This is the same problem as your other question. Do all processing that belongs to one test inside the `test('xxx', () { your test code here });' If you have code that should be executed before each or after each test add `setUp` and `tearDown` functions. See https://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-unit-tests/

Comment: Thank you, I will try to re-factor my code properly and come up with a small example that may be problematic. If so, I will open another topic for it.